# How to decompile a ex4 file new build 600+

Tags: mql4, mql5, forex

If you don't know, an ex4 file is a file created in the MQL language (Auto trading robots).

There is a decompiler that can decompile old builds of this type of files, but after build 600 there is no decompiler.

I have valuable EAs(Forex robot) that I need decompiled. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Based on [this forum post](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/156054) started 06/29/2015 it likely isn't *possible* AFATK... You could try [this tool](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xP0n-fPT0ITZ4REVrc5I5n07S4W8xD62wI_PHzG6ps4/edit) but I would run it through a virus checker as after I downloaded it some weird ads popped up...I also found [a decompiling service](https://www.fiverr.com/mcapple/decompile-two-ex4-files-to-mq4-metatrader-source-codes) but that likely isn't ideal...Or try the download [from this page](http://www.autotradeblog.net/2013/11/ex4-to-mq4-decompiler.html) (translate?)

Comment: Is **Forex** ("_The foreign exchange market (forex, FX, or currency market) is a form of exchange for the global decentralized trading of international currencies._") the correct tag, or should there be a new one to capture the notion of the robotics aspect?

Comment: Forex, the foreign exchange, right

Comment: I have this decompiler: http://prntscr.com/dtxndr but can't decompile new build EAs, if we don't have the decompiler tools to use, what other choice we have? and about that service, he uses the same decompiler that i have and only can decompile old builds

Comment: That's not impossible, because some people can do that, but wouldn't tell me how

Comment: It's not all that easy to code up a decompiler against a platform that you don't have the source for and that is always changing. Especially true if not being compensated for the time involved. Those who advertise these services are inevitably shut down.

Comment: @Micheal Can you share the files with me? If possible then can you share the source code if you have it then?

Answer (score 0):

Recent ex4 files cannot be decompiled, and since most of the EA's and indicators out there, which are published without the source code, are there to protect their creators under copyright laws, it is not recommended to use or recommend such decompiling programs.